# Gremlin query - sort response by field value

Tags: gremlin

I have the following query which retrieves course data connected to a student entity.

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('student').
  has('studentId', ':studentId').
  inE('studentBelongsToCourse').
  has('status', 'active').
  outV().
  hasLabel('course').
  has('status', 'active').
  dedup().
  by('externalId').
  valueMap('externalId', 'term').
  range(:offSet, :limit);
```

Is it possible to sort the response by the `TERM` field? which is part of the `course` entity.

For example, have items with `Fall` term appear before `Winter` term, like so:

```
[
{
  externalId: courseA,
  term: Fall,
},
{
  externalId: courseA,
  term: Winter,
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [`order().by()`](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#order-step) steps within Gremlin to order the vertices and then return the values as shown here:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('student').
  has('studentId', ':studentId').
  inE('studentBelongsToCourse').
  has('status', 'active').
  outV().
  hasLabel('course').
  has('status', 'active').
  dedup().
  by('externalId').
  order().by('term').
  valueMap('externalId', 'term').
  range(:offSet, :limit);
```

Comment: But the order will be alphabetical no?

Comment: Yes, that will sort by alphabetical order, which will give you the answer above.  Are you looking to perform some sort of custom sorting?  If so, then that is not currently possible in Gremlin